# Error : java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider

Tags: java, android

he escrito una aplicacion en java para android y no localizo el motivo por el que me aparece el siguiente error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
> com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord
> requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related
> APIs

el problema lo tengo intentando cargar en un hilo secundario un servicio para redimensionar imagener. Intenta obtener el nombre del fichero de una fotografia y se produce el error en el *getContentResolver*. Esto funcionaba hace un par de dias, pero ha dejado de funcionar, y no entiendo el motivo...

pongo trozos de mi codigo:

**Primero tema permisos**

```
   private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 101;  
   private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 102;

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
            //resume tasks needing this permission
        }
    }



  @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 if (
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ){

            // Permission is not granted
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                                                                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            } else {
                // No explanation needed; request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(  this,
                                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                                                                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            } else {
                // No explanation needed; request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(  this,
                                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
```

**carga del servicio en background**

```
  public void iniciarServicio() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, ProgramadorEnvios.class);
        JobInfo info = new JobInfo  .Builder(ID_SERVICIO, componentName)
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setMinimumLatency(5*1000)
                .build();
        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        int resultado = scheduler.schedule(info);
        if (resultado == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Job Acabado");
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Job Ha Fallado");
        }
    }
```

**El codigo que falla**

```
 public Uri resizeBitmap(Uri uri) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        String nueva_imagen = null;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
            Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); // esta es la linea con el error
            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    nueva_imagen = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
```

Seguro que es evidente, pero por mas que lo miro no veo el problema. a ver si alguien me puede dar algo de luz...

Gracias

Comment: Mira esta doc de android a ver si te ayuda https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT e igualmente si estás pidiendo un permiso de WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE es una api superior a 28, recibirás un crash, debes comprobar la versión de Android, desde Q incluída el permiso es read y de Q para abajo el permiso es lo que necesites (READ, WRITE...)

Comment: Me lo miro...

De todas maneras la version que estoy utilizando es minimo 26, target 28... para visualizar y modificar fotografias me funciona bien, el problema lo tengo para obtener el fichero del video y modificarlo... es como si la uri no fuera correcta jamas o no tuviera permisos...

a traves del Device File Explorer, cual seria la ruta correcta para acceder a ese video, a malas provaria a hardcodearla, para probar si funciona...
ahora mismo la ruta que pruebo es file://storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20200803_092411.mp4, pero segun el DFL no tengo permisos...

Comment: Prueba a añadir un FileProvifer en el manifest, con su xml para la ruta y después recupera la uri así:     val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.FILES_AUTHORITY, tempFile) dónde tempFile es File(this.cacheDir, fileName)... así lo he configurado para compartir imágenes guardadas y debería funcionar aunque sea un video...

Comment: ya tenia uno, igual es que no esta bien configurado...

<provider   android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
                    android:authorities="com.rv.upload.fileprovider"
                    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
                    android:exported="false">
                    <!--android:forceUriPermissions="true"-->
            <meta-data  android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>

no veo tampoco de donde sale BuildConfig.FILES_AUTHORITY

Answer (score 0):

Te paso el FileProvider que tengo configurado.
Manifest:

```
<provider
  android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="${filesAuthority}"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths_app" />
</provider>
```

provider_paths_app.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

El filesAuthority no es más que un String que declaré en el gradle para acceder desde el Manifest y desde el código:

```
static def setFileProviderByType(buildType, String appSuffix) {
    def filesAuthorityValue = Config.APP_ID + appSuffix + ".fileProvider"
    buildType.manifestPlaceholders = [filesAuthority: filesAuthorityValue]
    buildType.buildConfigField("String", "FILES_AUTHORITY", "\"${filesAuthorityValue}\"")
}
```

Poner al final ".fileProvider" es obligatorio para reconocer el FileProvier

Comment: Vas a tener que disculparme pero es la primera apliacion que hago para android/java y hay cosas en las que me pierdo...  

Entiendo que :  
a) def es un tipo de retorno que tengo que rellenar yo, aunque me parece mas que deveria ser un String  
b) buildType hay que substituirlo por un tipo y nombre de variable de variable que me vaya bien por contexto  
c) [filesAuthority: filesAuthorityValue] deberia salir del manifiesto  
d) "${filesAuthorityValue}\" deberia ser com.mi_app.fileprovider  
  
Si?

Answer (score 0):

La idea es que el filesAuthority es un string que tienes que usar en el manifest y también para recuperar tu archivo desde el files provider, se puede usar un string hardcodeado que debe tener el formato:

- Config.APP = app.miproyecto // la ruta que aparece después de la
  carpeta java
- appSuffix = Te lo facilita la clase BaseConfigImpl, es una id de la aplicación
- Y por último “.fileProvider”

El caso es que yo no quería hardcodear un string porque es una constante que se debe utilizar en dos sitios a la vez, y la forma de que el Manifst pueda llamar a un string declarado previamente, es a través de Gradle, por lo que “def” te permite declarar variables en Groovy (lenguaje de Gradle).